# How do i convert for (i = 1, I <= n, i ++) into a while loop?

Tags: python

I need to convert this loop into a while loop for homework:
for (i = 1, I <= n, i ++)

Please help as i am new to the language and am not really sure what to do.Also and explanation would be really useful so i can tackle future questions myself.
I have tried to convert it myself but do not fully understand exactly what to do.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: honestly, if someone gives you the answer here, you may not be able to work through things for yourself. As a hint: ask yourself this: The for loop, each iteration what is happening to the variable `i` ? and when does it stop?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow...https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer ...also...look in your text book for "While Loops"

Comment: Consider revising the syntax for for-loops and while-loops. The given for-loop isn't a Python for-loop (more like C/Java) – not sure where it came from – but looking up C syntax for for-loops and comparing to Python while-loops should help.

Comment: In general, `while` loop is not equivalent to `for` loop, because `while` loop body is always executed at least once, even if `n` in your case is `1`. And like people above noticed, if you are new to the language, textbook/tutorials/lessons will be much more helpful than StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

just try like below

```
i = 0
while i<n:
  i +=1
print(i)
```

You can find a lot of tutorial on Google about various loop

Comment: This is a bad example. It doesn't make use of any of python's excellent for loops, instead literally interpreting the for loop in python.

Comment: @101arrowz op want to just convert and i am not try to make any others

Comment: @101arrowz: The OP specifically asks for "into a while loop?". Why have you downvoted? Moreover, your answer was with for loop. The OP hasn't asked for it. Please read the question title

Comment: I misread the question, my bad. I still believe that it is silly to convert to a while loop for this particular example, but if you must this answer is correct. Unfortunately I can't change my vote unless he changes the answer.

Comment: Wouldn't it be kinder in this instance not to provide an answer? Paritosh's comment on the original post is very apropos

Comment: @101arrowz why not you think about learning? op may want to learn it i mean conversion and based on what i will change my answer?

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin I misinterpreted the question, as I said. I apologize for downvoting. Please change your post and Stack Overflow will allow me to remove my downvote. I completely agree with what you are saying now that I see he specifically said "while loop".

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin I did, but someone else downvoted so I upvoted.

Comment: @101arrowz for future reference, SO discourages the practice of upvoting to balance out a score: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311406/is-it-wrong-to-use-an-upvote-to-balance-out-a-downvote